# I don't know what happened in terminal

Tags: terminal, mono

I have some problem and I don't know at all... Here is my shell.

```
Last login: Tue Jun  6 20:20:15 on ttys000
-bash: home/username/programs/apache-maven-3.5.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bi
n:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/share/dotnet:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Ver
sions/Current/Commands: No such file or directory
-bash: uname: command not found
-bash: ps: command not found
-bash: touch: command not found
```

I already googling but I can't find answer... what is this problem and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It look like your PATH environment variable setting wrong value.

change `home/username/programs/apache-maven-3.5.0/bin` to `/home/username/programs/apache-maven-3.5.0/bin`

or just to deleted it